# Refused to execute script from "*" because its MIME type ('text/HTML') is not executable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mime

I'm plotting some markers on a Google Map according to their locations defined in a Google Sheet.

For one Google Sheet the markers are plotted but if I make a copy of this sheet and launch my web page, I've got this message error:

> Refused to execute script from 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/MYDOMAIN/s/My-Script-ID/exec?Jsonp=callback' because its MIME type ('text/HTML') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Here is my HTML page with some JavaScript code.

```js
//.. my html code

    <script type=application/javascript>
    var DATA_SERVICE_URL ="https://script.google.com/a/macros/MYDOMAIN/s/MYSCRIPTID/exec?jsonp=callback"; // THIS ONE WORKS

    //var DATA_SERVICE_URL_COPY = "https://script.google.com/a/macros/MYDOMAIN/s/MYSCRIPTID/exec?jsonp=callback"; // **THIS ONE IS NOT WORKING** (it is linked to the copy of my working google sheet above)

    //....

var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
scriptElement.src = DATA_SERVICE_URL; 
document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptElement);

    function callback(data) {

    alert("Here am I");

    //.. Plotting markers on map

    }

    </script>
```

When I use DATA_SERVICE_URL_COPY instead of DATA_SERVICE_URL, I got the message error. But both Google Sheet are published, with the same options.

Below is the Google Apps Script I use in both Google Sheets.

```js
var SPREADSHEET_ID = 'MY SPREADSHEET ID';
var SHEET_NAME = 'MAP';
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function doGet(request){
  var callback = request.parameters.jsonp;
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME).getDataRange();
  var json = callback + '(' + Utilities.jsonStringify(range.getValues()) + ')' ;


  return ContentService.createTextOutput(json).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function testDoGet() {

  var request = {parameters: {jsonp: 'callback'}};
  var results = doGet(request);

  Logger.log(results.getContent());
}
```

I guess the problem comes from the Google Sheet, but I don't know where exactly?

Does someone have a clue?

Comment: Years late.. but I think the problem is with the MIME type of Google Drive such that it considers all documents as text/html.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the issue.

(line:15) Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Change 
     `<script type=application/javascript>`
to 
     `<script type="application/javascript">`